# Copy Pivot Table Values and Format on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, powerpivot

How do I copy and paste a value in a pivot table and also at the same time copying its format if combined with text. There will be like multiple concatenations on the destination cell.

I cannot seem to make it work (cell A7 is my try).

Please see below.

[image]

Comment: As with any other source, you will need to format the numeric values, in your `A7` formula, using the `TEXT` function.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an answer to referring to formatting of a cell without using vba, but indirectly you might get the desired result by using the camera tool/linked picture referring to the cell(s) you need.
This will exactly show what and how you want it.
Not sure if that's something you desire to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
=Round(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of Sales Value in Euro]",$A$3)/1000,1)&"K Eur ("&Round(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of Value % Chg YA]",$A$3),2)&"%)"
```

Comment: That's creating the same format as the description. I was trying to find a solution for actual copying the format of a cell, not recreating. But your solution is probably what he's looking for.

Comment: At first I also thought that he wants exactly the same format.  But if the image uploaded is carefully seen, it becomes clear that format of copied cell and desired output are not exactly same.  Perhaps user wants to reformat the output only. Let him clarify.